# Json after json_encode showing wrong value after insert in database

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to save multidimensional array in database using json_encode. if i echo json string its showing right output but in database string is changed after insert.

here is my code:

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
$watchlist=$_POST['watchlist'];
$watchshow=$_POST['watchshow'];
$yearshow=$_POST['yearshow'];

$quer = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
$q = mysqli_query($conn, $quer);
$count=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
$email = $row['email'];
$count++;
}

if($count==1) //if user already exist change greeting text to "Welcome Back"
{
$quer = "SELECT watchlist FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
$q = mysqli_query($conn, $quer);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
$watch = $row['watchlist'];
}
$data = json_decode($watch, TRUE);
array_push($data,$watchlist);
$add=array();
array_push($add,$watchshow);
array_push($add,$yearshow);

$data[] = $add;

$t = json_encode($data , JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

$sql = "update users set watchlist='$t' WHERE email='$email'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo'updated';          
} else {
echo'error';         
}             
}
else            { 
$new=array();
array_push($new,$watchlist);
$add=array();
array_push($add,$watchshow);
array_push($add,$yearshow);
$new[] = $add;
$name = json_encode($new);

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO users (email,watchlist)
VALUES ('$email','$name')";
if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) {
echo 'success';
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql1 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}
```

if i echo $name output is

```
{"0":{"0":"Stranger Things","1":2017}}
```

but after insert it's showing this in database

```
{"0":"Stranger Things","1":{"0":"Stranger Things","1":"2017"}}
```

what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: At what point are you echoing the string for checking? Is the database column JSON type or a plain string?

Comment: column type is varchar there is no option for json type on my host

Comment: if i echo $name its showing right output

Comment: And what do you see in DB? Are there right data?

Comment: after insert in database its showing  {"0":"Stranger Things","1":{"0":"Stranger Things","1":"2017"}}

Comment: Is this code in loop?

Comment: this code is in if else. if new record insert if not update row

Comment: Try to hardcode `$name` as `{"0":{"0":"Stranger Things","1":2017}}`

Comment: If the column is just a plain varchar and you're echoing the string right before insertion, there should be nothing there that changes it whatsoever, and we cannot see any problem here.

Comment: What is the type of the 'watchlist' column?

Comment: _“this code is in if else. if new record insert if not update row”_ - then probably that second part, the update, is going wrong …? Your output clearly looks as if something that already existed before was appended to, only in the wrong place somehow.

Comment: no if I insert new record its showing wrong insert and same for update too.

Comment: I added full code.

Comment: Sorry its my fault. It was post that causing problem its because I use same variable name in two different files and then using them in same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You placed echo to unnecessary variable somewhere in your code thats why it prints name 2 times.. check it properly and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

```
{"0":"Stranger Things","1":{"0":"Stranger Things","1":"2017"}}
```

This is happening most probably due to  `$new[] = $add;` when you are using Loop and passing some value inside `$new[i]`.

In first Loop its proper `{"0":"Stranger Things","1":2017}` 
Now in second loop when i will be 1.

So, in position of 1 , `{"0":"Stranger Things","1":2017}` this is getting inserted again and making final array as `{"0":"Stranger Things","1":{"0":"Stranger Things","1":"2017"}}`

> Show the complete code as it is, to identify the error.

As per the code you have provided, output must be correct.

```
$email= "abc@gmail.com";
$watchshow="Stranger Things";
$yearshow= 2017;
$new=array();
$add=array();
array_push($add,$watchshow);
array_push($add,$yearshow);

$new[] = $add;

$add=array();
array_push($add,$watchshow);
array_push($add,$yearshow);
$new[] = $add;

echo $name = json_encode($new, true);
```

Comment: I added full code.